# Static Algorithm for giving response after user input

Tags: php, algorithm

I have 2 arrays: `F of length 4 and S of length 25`
User can select any no of these elements from the above two arrays 
For eg selecting any 2 from F and 10 from S.Based on what user selected i have give a response to the user from my another `array R of length 100`.
I tried making if else but was exhausted after creating 
100s of them.
So is there any better approach for this ?

My goal is to give user one of the index from array R.

PS. There is no AI(Artificial Intelligence) involved.

EDIT
Currently what i have done is :

```
if(in_array(1,$F) && in_array(12,$S)){
   return $R[3];
}else if(in_array(1,$F) && in_array(17,$s)){
   return $R[91];
}else if(in_array(2,$F) && in_array(1,$F) && in_array(21,$S) &&  in_array(25,$S)){
   return $R[23];
}else if(in_array(3,$F) && in_array(21,$S) && in_array(7,$S)){
   return $R[17];
}..........
```

Comment: What? what is the question? Some code would be nice! What is your goal?!

Comment: Do you have all those arrays already?

Comment: Yes I have all those array ready.

Comment: So, return `$array100[2*10]`. Your index could be 2*10.

Comment: The algorithm description is not clear.

Comment: @sectus i want to use what the user has given as input and based on that suggest what i want to give to user from the array R.
So i just want to remove the hassle of if and else statements.

Comment: Please, show few `if`s

Comment: So where is the user input in this code? Not to mention that you miss some `$` signs there.

Comment: @zerkms S and F are user inputs

Comment: Just create a map `id => [[ids in F], [ids in S]]` and iterate over it.

Comment: @zerkms currently there are 2 arrays but in future this can change.

Comment: So what is the rule? "Suggest something from R based on input" is no rule. Is the choice random? If not, how is the choice related to the input? If you have a rule, tell us; it shouldn't be that hard to express it as an algorithm in code then. If you don't have any rule, we can't really help you find one because we have no idea what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Creating map like @zerkms mentioned.

```
function getRKey(array $f, array $s)
    {
    // values map by order
    $map_r_array = [
        3 => ['f' => [1], 's' => [12]],
        91 => ['f' => [1], 's' => [17]],
        23 => ['f' => [1, 2], 's' => [21, 25]],
        17 => ['f' => [3], 's' => [7, 21]],
    ];
    foreach ($map_r_array as $key => $check)
        {
        // check one by one.
        if (!array_diff($check['f'], $f) && !array_diff($check['s'], $s))
            {
            return $key;
            }
        }
    return null;
    }

$f = [1, 2, 3];
$s = [7, 21];

var_dump(getRKey($f, $s)); // int(17)
```